# Encoding conflict in mysql between iOS and Android

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I inherited support of existing app system consisting of two mobile apps - on iOS and Android + mysql db controlled by php API.

Users using both apps can read and write strings to mysql table, often using country specific chars, like German or Spanish.

DB table has **utf8_unicode_ci** encoding.

**mb_detect_encoding()** method in php API file claims both iOS and Android strings are UTF-8.

Now, heading to the problem. After some time it occured that special chars are inserted to db differently in case of iOS and Android. I can't find the way to properly convert Android string into similar to iOS one (which is compatible with json_encode). I tried various options, the closest one was when i simply run utf8_encode($android_string), but still only some chars are encoded in the same way as in iOS.

Example:

- source string - `óśćąę`
- db content from iOS - `Ã³Å›Ä‡Ä…Ä™`     <- expected
- db content from Android - `ó????`      <- json_encode returns null
- db content from utf8(Android) - `Ã³????`   <- json_encode is ok, but returns `?`, not letters

Do you know the good way to convert in php 'Android' string to look the same as 'iOS' one?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to try and fix the Android app so that it sends correctly UTF-8 encoded data in the first place …?

Comment: Of course it would be better and Android dev is working on it now. But the app is already published for some time and has plenty of users - so it's a matter of backward compatibility.

Comment: Well then I’d suggest capturing some of the content send from the Android app – before any encoding conversion and sending it to the database – and look at the hex byte values to try and figure out what encoding these are actually send in.

Comment: Good point! That was it... Looks like some unique codes were lost already in Android, so utf8_encode was working correctly, but some unique chars never left Android device...